# Get reviews with Google Search API for Shopping

Tags: api, google-shopping-api

Is it possible to get the reviews of a product using Google Search API for Shopping.
I mean... If I look for an Iphone 4G. How do I get the reviews for that product? They are in the search results, but no when using the API
thanks

Answer (score 1):

Those reviews are not currently available from the Search API for Shopping.

Comment: Can you add a reference to support your answer?

Comment: Of course, if it was available it would be documented here: http://code.google.com/apis/shopping/search/v1/getting_started.html which it isn't, so it isn't.